# Subversion - reconcile changes after deleting/recreating a directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a process that updates the contents of a folder by deleting the entire folder, re-creating it, and then populating files.  Unfortunately that deletes the .svn folders which makes svn unhappy.  What process can I use to delete a folder, write some files, and then tell svn to reconsile the differences (i.e. recognize that I've created some files with the same name but updated contents, some files no longer exist, new files have been added)?  The solution should work for subfolders as well, since those will be delete/recreated in the process.

Comment: Why are you deleting and recreating rather then just updating?  What is the use-case for this?

Comment: Third-party software is doing the update via delete/recreate, so I have no control of the process.  At a high-level, this software is updating "plug-ins" where each plug-in is contained within a folder (with subfolders containing plug-in specific code/data/etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit confused what you're looking for. If you have a process that creates the folders and data, why store the folders and subfolders in Subversion? Subversion should be only for source and not generated content.

I wish there was a bit more explanation what you're doing and why.

We had someone use [Robohelp](http://www.adobe.com/products/robohelp.html) to maintain the HTML files we had in our source code. Robohelp generates HTML files from MS-Word documents. When it does a regeneration, file names, sizes, and directories could change even with the most minor of changes. The old method was deleting everything and readding it back in. That was difficult for the tech writers to do and generated thousands of changes in a single Subversion revision.

In the end, we stored the Word doc files in Subversion. The generated HTML was removed. However, we did store a single ZIP containing all the HTML (since our Unix build process couldn't generate the HTML from Robohelp). When a new set of help files were regenerated, the Tech writers simply zipped it up and replaced the zip file in our Subversion repository. No more massive adds and deletes.

Are you attempting to synchronize work someone is doing out of Subversion into Subversion? For example, someone downloads the files via `svn export`, does their work, and it's your job to check in all the changes. In that case, you should write a little script to go through and compare everything in directory #1 to everything in directory #2 and make the changes that way. I believe we did this in three passes. First time, deleting everything in Directory #1 that's not in Directory #2, then adding everything in Directory #2 that's not in Directory #1. And, finally doing a comparison of all files in directory #1 and directory #2 and committing these changes.

Comment: great questions.  Without getting into the gory details this is a case where its a huge pain to update these folders via my build process (mostly from a performance/reliability POV).  The update itself requires a bit of nursing, sometime it fails because of connectivity at provider's site, and if it fails the error must be detected through text file parsing!) In other words, its not something that I want to run with each build- its a process I'll run from time-to-time on my local machine and check-in the changes.

Comment: @SFun28: Have you looked at [git-svn](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html)? If you have bad connectivity to your repository, you'll have problems with Subversion which requires a central repo. Git doesn't. Git SVN allows you to use Git locally while talking to a Subversion server. Not sure exactly what this might do for you, but it might help.

Comment: @SFun28: How about a Subversion `svn co` and a `svn export`? You could copy the `svn export` directory over the `svn checkout` one. That'll allow you to make massive changes, but the copy won't touch the `.svn` files (since the export won't have them).

Comment: the connectivity issue is with the third party provider, not my own repository, but I've been exploring git anyways for its advantages over svn.  Great idea about svn export!!!  that's the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to script/code this yourself.

Either: backup all the .svn folders and put them back in place after your 3. party have done its thing, or keep a 2. working copy nearby and copy over all the files from the 1. working copy which the 3. party have updated.

Then, find all the removed files with `svn status`, the ones marked 'D' and issue svn rm on those. Find all the new files with svn status, marked `?` and svn add those.

Finally run svn commit.